# Windows set File permissions to match -rwxrwxrwx

Tags: windows, file-permissions

In my cgi-bin for Apache on my local windows environment I have several .cgi files with permissions -rwxrwxrwx . I'm getting one error on my application, http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fcgi-bin%2Ftinyows.exe 500 (Internal Server Error).
Which is mentioning proxy.cgi and when I looked at permissions using `ls -l` it is indeed alone with the permissions -rw-rw-rw. I ran `chmod -777 proxy.cgi` which spit out no error but didn't effect the file. I then ran `proxy.cgi /grant everyone:F` which updated some things but not the underlying -rw-rw-rw.

Comment: Are you asking how to change permissions on your proxy.cgi file, or whether the permissions on that file are indeed the root cause of the application error?

Comment: It's my starting point because it's the only thing that I suspect is wrong, so how to change the permissions is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Windows file systems don't have Unix permissions. The only related file attribute is the read-only attribute, which affects all users equally. Some file systems such as NTFS support object security (a generic system, not just for files), which uses a security descriptor (SD) with an owner, group, and access control entries (ACEs) in two lists: the discretionary list (DACL) and the system list (SACL). Generally we're interested in the DACL, which has entries that either allow or deny access rights. The SACL is mostly audit entries, but it can have a mandatory label that affects access.